# Unit tests in a database driven CodeIgniter web-application

Tags: database, unit-testing, codeigniter, testing

CodeIgniter comes with a Unit Testing class built in, and I would very much like to use it. However, almost all functions I would want to test interact with the database by adding records, deleting records, etc. How would I, for example, write tests for the 'create user' function without actually creating users every time I run the test?

Upon some further research, it seems I need to be using Mock objects for external services like the database, etc. I haven't been able to find much in the way of docs on how to do that besides this one forum thread:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/106737

Is there any actual documentation?

Comment: This is all going to depend on what framework you use for your unit tests. Do you have one picked yet?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the docs, CodeIgniter has its own unit testing framework built in. Is that not correct?

Comment: CodeIgniter 2 does indeed have a testing framework built in. It's not perfect from what I've seen, but good enough to get started. Mock objects would be the ideal way to go, but that is something that's missing from CI so there is no official documentation. The article you linked to looks like a good starting point.

Comment: try this library: https://github.com/kenjis/ci-phpunit-test to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your database driver allows transactions, use them.  Do whatever needs to be tested, then rollback (on success or failure).

I've found that it's hard to run unit tests with controller actions.  If you find a good way of doing that, let us know!

Comment: actually this seems like a really good solution. Unit testing controllers isn't easy but if you put the bulk of your code inside models, you can unit test those no problem